# Not able to uniquely identify a checkbox in qtp

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I am working on a windows form .Net application using QTP and there are a set of checkboxes which are repeated and all have the same property.I need to select the one particular checkbox from each set.If the checkbox is not visible on the screen then we need to scrool down else in pops a error message.Is there a way to select one particular checkbox from each set.
eq:
abc feature
1
2
3
abc feature
1
2
3
4
abc feature
1
2

i need to select checkbox 1 from all the set.

Answer (score 3):

You need to find a way to identify a "checkbox set" use the object spy or a dom inspector to see what identifies the set (probably some kind of `div` or `span`) for the sake of this answer I'll assume that it's a `div` with a specific `class` `"chkbxGrp"`.

Then look for the first checkbox contained within this group and check it.

Note that scrolling the checkboxs into view is done automatically by QTP.
If you need to fail this when an expected group doesn't exist you will have to find out how to identify specific groups and then use the expected values in the test rather than iterating over all such groups.

```
' Untested code
Set Desc = Description.Create()
Desc("html tag").Value = "div"
Desc("html tag").RegularExpression = False
Desc("class").Value = "chkbxGrp"
' Find all groups
Set groups = Browser("B").Page("P").ChildObjects(Desc)
For i = 0 To groups.Count -1
    ' in each group check the first checkbox
    groups(i).WebCheckBox("index:=0").Set "ON"
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "identify" the checkbox using QTP index.
It's not the best option to do, though if you need only the 1st checkbox.
Just look for all Objects on the page of a type "CheckBox", and if the result set > 0, get the first one.

The second option is to "locate" the Checkbox by the nearby elements, but in this case you need to be sure that their location is NOT to be changed.

BTW, are you sure they are completely identical?  In QTP there is an option  to set necessary attributes for elements location. You can add any attribute which is unique for the CheckBoxes appearing in your app.